# How can I add a window selection tool when pinning a window in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: windows-10, gnome-shell, window

In Windows 10, when you snap a window to the left/right half of the screen, a little dialog pops up enabling you to click on a window to automatically pin to the other half. Is there any way I can replicate this in Ubuntu (Gnome)?